# opencart multistore product page redirecting to default page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

i have create multistore in opencart but the every page in the subdomain is redirecting the default store so that if i add the product to cart in default it is coming in sub store cart also.

Kindly help me

Comment: make sure that each store has a link of the form `http://bla bla.com/`

Comment: From admin panel goto `System->Settings->Edit store-> Server tab` and there change `Use Shared Sessions` to `No` if it is `Yes`.

Comment: Have you created a sub domains for stores ?